Excel VBA : How to scrap a single value from yahoo finance webpage
I am trying to scrap the live BTC value on the yahoo finance webpage and store it in a cell.
The html structure is :
<fin-streamer class="livePrice yf-1tejb6" data-symbol="BTC-USD" data-testid="qsp-price" data-field="regularMarketPrice" data-trend="none" data-pricehint="2" data-value="69313.64" active="">
     <span>69,313.64</span>
</fin-streamer>

The value I want to store in a cell on a spreadsheet is 69,313.64.
Here is my code :
Private Sub Enter_Click()

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim Website As String
Dim value As Variant

Website = "https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/"
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

request.Open "GET", Website, False
request.send
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
html.body.innerHTML = response

value = html.getElementsByClassName("livePrice yf-1tejb6").Item(0).innerText
Range("AE1").value = value

End Sub

The line
value = html.getElementsByClassName("livePrice yf-1tejb6").Item(0).innerText

returns a "Runtime Error 91 : Object Variable or With block varaible not set". How shoud I fix the code and get the value? Thank you!

Which line throws the error? Have you checked if the response contains the required information/class/line?

Oh, when I run 'MsgBox(response)', it does not contain the full html structure of the webpage.

Would you like to see the history starting from first of January 2000?   If so, it is possible to start only from Sep 17, 2014... What do you expect from request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"? How do you manually check the mentioned reference amount? Your code works as it should (with or without the above mention code line), but returning 70,960.35.

@VBasic2008 you mean the url in my code? It is simply a web page where we get an overview of BTC. The code is to get the live closing price of BTC.

@FaneDuru Oh my bad, that line of code is insignificant. I will remove it. Thanks for pointing it out.

You can try the V8 Chart API from Yahoo as below;
Sub GetBTC()
    Dim URL As String, valBTC As Variant
    
    URL = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/BTC-USD"
    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        valBTC = Split(Split(.responseText, """regularMarketPrice"":")(1), ",")(0)
    End With
        
    MsgBox valBTC
End Sub


Nice and compact. Voted it up!

Can you kindly explain how the line valBTC = Split(Split(.responseText, """regularMarketPrice"":")(1), ",")(0) get the value? Thank you!

The XMLHTTP request returns a JSON text in the responseText and the current value of BTC-USD lies in between "regularMarketPrice": and a ,. Using the SPLIT function twice, we pick the required value.

Much appreciated!
